# NDK causing issues

Tags: android, android-ndk, android-6.0-marshmallow

I have a note 4 on which I have android 6.0

My application is crashing on this device. Below is the crash log.

```
12-08 11:24:15.044 14005 14005 E AndroidRuntime: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: dlopen failed: cannot locate symbol "__aeabi_atexit" referenced by "/data/app/bla.bla.bla-1/lib/arm/libblabla.so"...
12-08 11:24:15.044 14005 14005 E AndroidRuntime:    at java.lang.Runtime.loadLibrary(Runtime.java:372)
12-08 11:24:15.044 14005 14005 E AndroidRuntime:    at java.lang.System.loadLibrary(System.java:1076)
12-08 11:24:15.044 14005 14005 E AndroidRuntime:    at bla.bla.bla.JNIMapperUtil.<clinit>(SourceFile:13)
12-08 11:24:15.044 14005 14005 E AndroidRuntime:    at bla.bla.bla.onCreate(SourceFile:35)
12-08 11:24:15.044 14005 14005 E AndroidRuntime:    at android.app.Instrumentation.callApplicationOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1036)
12-08 11:24:15.044 14005 14005 E AndroidRuntime:    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:6317)
12-08 11:24:15.044 14005 14005 E AndroidRuntime:    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1800(ActivityThread.java:221)
12-08 11:24:15.044 14005 14005 E AndroidRuntime:    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1860)
12-08 11:24:15.044 14005 14005 E AndroidRuntime:    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
12-08 11:24:15.044 14005 14005 E AndroidRuntime:    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:158)
12-08 11:24:15.044 14005 14005 E AndroidRuntime:    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7225)
12-08 11:24:15.044 14005 14005 E AndroidRuntime:    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
12-08 11:24:15.044 14005 14005 E AndroidRuntime:    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1230)
12-08 11:24:15.044 14005 14005 E AndroidRuntime:    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1120)
```

Please note that the application works fine on s6 and later version. and also older devices with previous android versions. The problems ovvurs with the updated android software on older devices.

Thanks.

Comment: What is your `APP_PLATFORM` set to? It should not be higher than your `minSdkVersion`.

Answer (score 0):

Fixed the issue.

Was using stlport_static. Instead used gnustl_shared.